# Remove a git fork on server

Tags: linux, git, terminal

For school we use git to submit things. Every question here seems to be dealing with GitHub and isnt answering my specific question.

In our lab we were attempting to download the files but the prof was having issues on his end. He was asking me to try some commands etc. Anyways we did this:

ssh csci fork csci/Labs csci/$USER/Labs

git clone csci:csci/$USER/Labs

And it worked but the files had issues or something. He said he will get the sys admin to fix it. Then today he told me I need to delete my version on the server and just do it over again. I asked if I can just rm -r the folder but he said I need to delete the one on the git server - he said he doesnt know the command but I should be able to look it up.

I tried

git remote remove csci/Labs

but that did not work. I already deleted the local folder (before he told me about it actually) using rm -r Labs, and saying yes to the delete this git file warnings or  whatever. So Im not sure where to go from here to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A repository is just a directory with working copy (though it is optional) and .git, so deleting the directory deletes the repository. To delete a remote repository you need to have access to the remote filesystem.
Try to run which should work also.

```
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: Oh okay. So all I had to do on my part was delete the local files. And only the system admin can delete the serverside stuff. Okay that makes sense. Thank you, if theres any problems I will talk to the prof or go to the sys admin.